# React children count

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i have a component like this

```
       <Slider 
         Arrows
         Autoplay
       >
          <SliderContentMall />
       </Slider>
```

and in SliderContentMall i make a map like this

```
const SliderContentMall = (props) => 
{
    return (
        props.Data.map(DataValue =>
        {
            return (
                <TouchableOpacity style={Styles.ImageContainer} onPress={() => {}>

                </TouchableOpacity>
            )
        })
    );
}
```

this map returns 3 object the things is in the slider component when i do

```
  console.log(React.Children.count(this.props.children))
```

it only return 1 and i need the count of the 3, i cant make the map in the slider directly the map needs to be in the SliderContentMall

Comment: what is the length of ```props.Data``` array?

Comment: the length is 3

Comment: post the remaining code.

Comment: You could explicitly count the `Data` property of the `TouchableOpacity` children. `const touchables = [];` `React.Children.forEach(child => child.type == TouchableOpacity && touchables.push(child));` then lastly `const sum = touchables.reduce((sum, child) => sum + child.props.Data.length, 0);` But I doubt this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`React.Children.count` is doing what it's intended to do: there's a single child, and that child is a `<SliderContentMall>`. It's not going to check how many children are underneath that, and in fact it can't since those children havn't been rendered yet. Rendering goes from top down, so while you're rendering the `<Slider>`, you have not yet rendered the `<SliderContentMall>`, and thus the various `<TouchableOpacity>`'s havn't even been thought of yet.

If the slider needs to know how many pieces of data will be rendered, the most straightforward way to do that is as a prop to the slider. For example:

```
<Slider 
  Arrows
  Autoplay
  count={data.length}
>
  <SliderContentMall data={data}/>
</Slider>
```

Comment: you are right men i dont kwon react render the components top to down i cant use the data in the slider but i can use inside SliderContentMall the Slider component and all works fine

Answer (score 0):

You are using map function over props.Data instead of props.children.